# Rails Devise separate Edit registration form into two forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration, edit

I want to separate Devise's edit registration form into two separate pages, something like site/edit and site/settings. Settings page would be for fields like password, email, etc. while edit would just be for user information. How would I go about accomplishing this I haven't really found much documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this one out on my own and I didn't have to create a separate model, trying to keep everything simple for future integration. I'll post my answer for anyone else who may run into this problem. Surprised there wasn't clearer documentation on this.

**Create a separate RegistrationsController that inherits from Devise's generated controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def settings
        @member = current_member
        if @member 
            render :settings
        else
            render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
         end 
    end
 end
```

**Create the corresponding view in your Devise registrations folder (I just copied the fields I needed from the existing edit form) and then call to the method in your routes:**

```
devise_scope :member do 
     root :to => 'devise/registrations#new'
     match '/settings' => 'registrations#settings', as: :settings
end
```